# Fakeroot on OSX Monterey

Tags: macos, homebrew, dpkg, macos-monterey, fakeroot

How can I install fakeroot on OSX Monterey

Using `brew install fakeroot`:

```
Warning: fakeroot has been deprecated because it does not build!
Error: fakeroot: no bottle available!
You can try to install from source with:
  brew install --build-from-source fakeroot
Please note building from source is unsupported. You will encounter build
failures with some formulae. If you experience any issues please create pull
requests instead of asking for help on Homebrew's GitHub, Twitter or any other
official channels.
```

Using brew from sources `brew install --build-from-source fakeroot`:

```
Warning: fakeroot has been deprecated because it does not build!
==> Downloading https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?msg=5;filename=0001-Implement-openat-2-wrapper-which-handles-optional-ar.patch;att=1;bug=766649
Already downloaded: /Users/michal/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/e6d4dac68230de33e16ff9c899395f60a9dfbc703a45dc4e6bbed7e39eba44eb--0001-Implement-openat-2-wrapper-which-handles-optional-ar.patch
==> Downloading https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?msg=5;filename=0002-OS-X-10.10-introduced-id_t-int-in-gs-etpriority.patch;att=2;bug=766649
Already downloaded: /Users/michal/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/446b9b9c92c24195ef463099617d6e92a00027a69e8ba4478a8a01b7d28e372b--0002-OS-X-10.10-introduced-id_t-int-in-gs-etpriority.patch
==> Downloading https://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/f/fakeroot/fakeroot_1.24.orig.tar.gz
curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 404

Error: fakeroot: Failed to download resource "fakeroot"
Download failed: https://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/f/fakeroot/fakeroot_1.24.orig.tar.gz
```

Using `sudo port install fakeroot`:

```
--->  Computing dependencies for fakeroot
--->  Fetching archive for fakeroot
--->  Attempting to fetch fakeroot-1.24_0+universal.darwin_21.arm64-x86_64.tbz2 from https://packages.macports.org/fakeroot
--->  Attempting to fetch fakeroot-1.24_0+universal.darwin_21.arm64-x86_64.tbz2 from https://fra.de.packages.macports.org/fakeroot
--->  Attempting to fetch fakeroot-1.24_0+universal.darwin_21.arm64-x86_64.tbz2 from https://nue.de.packages.macports.org/fakeroot
--->  Building fakeroot
Error: Failed to build fakeroot: command execution failed
Error: See /opt/local/var/macports/logs/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_macports_release_tarballs_ports_sysutils_fakeroot/fakeroot/main.log for details.
Error: Follow https://guide.macports.org/#project.tickets if you believe there is a bug.
Error: Processing of port fakeroot failed
```

Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Here I found working version (only old 1.19),

```
http://mackyle.github.io/fakeroot/
```

I've installed by `pkg` installer, and all seems to be working